# Tensorflow layer incompatibilty Error while performing prediction

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, conv-neural-network, tf.keras, image-classification

I am performing transfer learning using `mobilenetV2`( `tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2`) as a base model.

After training, I predict on my testing set:

```py
img_b, label_b = test_ds.as_numpy_iterator().next()
predictions = model.predict_on_batch(img_b)
p_i = predictions[0]
print("Class: Confidence Percent")
print("Label: ", label_b[0])
for indx, prob in enumerate(p_i):
  print(f"{class_name_list[indx]} : {prob * 100}")
```

It works fine.
Output:

```bash
Class: Confidence Percent
Label:  0
=========================
Apple___Apple_scab : 99.96755123138428
Apple___Black_rot : 1.395771676016011e-05
Apple___Cedar_apple_rust : 0.030332594178617
Apple___healthy : 1.5776115136478808e-08
Blueberry___healthy : 2.7043674916647775e-11
Cherry___healthy : 6.673043344562757e-05
Cherry___Powdery_mildew : 0.0017889193259179592
Corn___Cercospora_leaf_spot Gray_leaf_spot : 3.2566850904913736e-05
Corn___Common_rust : 1.2238189128765953e-06
Corn___healthy : 3.638373213821211e-08
Corn___Northern_Leaf_Blight : 0.0002208115802204702
```

Then, I saved the model using: `model.save("model_tl.keras"))`
and load it using: `load_model = tf.keras.models.load_model("model_tl.keras")`

And I perform the same operation of prediction using `load_model`:

```py
predictions = load_model.predict_on_batch(img_b)
```

And I get the following error:

```bash
ValueError: in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 2440, in predict_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 2425, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 2413, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.predict_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 2381, in predict_step
        return self(x, training=False)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/input_spec.py", line 298, in assert_input_compatibility
        raise ValueError(

    ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'model' (type Functional).
    
    Input 0 of layer "sequential_1" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 256, 3), found shape=(16, 256, 256, 3)
    
    Call arguments received by layer 'model' (type Functional):
      • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(16, 256, 256, 3), dtype=uint8)
      • training=False
      • mask=None
```

Here, is img_b shape: `(16, 256, 256, 3)`
and `load_model` summary:

```
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 input_2 (InputLayer)        [(None, 256, 256, 3)]     0         
                                                                 
 sequential_1 (Sequential)   (256, 256, 3)             0         
                                                                 
 tf.math.truediv (TFOpLambd  (None, 256, 256, 3)       0         
 a)                                                              
                                                                 
 tf.math.subtract (TFOpLamb  (None, 256, 256, 3)       0         
 da)                                                             
                                                                 
 mobilenetv2_1.00_224 (Func  (None, 8, 8, 1280)        2257984   
 tional)                                                         
                                                                 
 global_average_pooling2d_2  (None, 1280)              0         
  (GlobalAveragePooling2D)                                       
                                                                 
 dropout (Dropout)           (None, 1280)              0         
                                                                 
 dense (Dense)               (None, 11)                14091     
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 2272075 (8.67 MB)
Trainable params: 1875531 (7.15 MB)
Non-trainable params: 396544 (1.51 MB)
_________________________________________________________________
```

This problem occur only when I perform prediction using saved model

Is this beacause of :  `sequential_1 (Sequential)   (256, 256, 3)             0` and not  `sequential_1 (Sequential)   (None, 256, 256, 3)             0`, `sequential_1` output shape does not have a batch size: `None`

Comment: Can you add the summary of the model before the saving process? Let's see if it is `predict_on_batch` causing such problem/behaviour.